# How can I get full path of FormControl in angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

How can I get the full path of FormControl in angular 4+?

I have the reactive form:

```
{
    name: '',
    address: {
        city: '',
        country: ''
    }
}
```

And I rly need to get full path of control:

```
const addressFormGroup = this.form.get('address');
const cityControl = addressFormGroup.get('city');
cityControl.plsGiveMeFullPath() //address.city
```

Is there existing method to get the full path of cityControl: FormControl | FormGroup?

Answer (score 5):

I implemented these two methods to get this functionality.

The first one is a helper that returns the name of a control (as it is indexed in its parent).  The function achieves that by searching on its parent's `controls` object the control that equals the one that you gave it, and then returning the key.

The second one is a recursive function that calls returns the name of the control using the helper above and calls itself for the control's parent, joining the return string with dots ('.').

```typescript
  getControlName(c: AbstractControl): string | null {
    if(!c.parent) return null;
    const formGroup = c.parent.controls;
    return Object.keys(formGroup).find(name => c === formGroup[name]) || null;
  }

  getControlPath(c: AbstractControl, path: string): string | null {
    path = this.getControlName(c) + path;

    if(c.parent && this.getControlName(c.parent)) {
      path = "."+path;
      return this.getControlPath(c.parent, path);
    } else {
      return path;
    }

  }
```

Comment: thanks. just a notice. you can use   if (path === '.') {
    path = getControlName(c);
  } else {
    path = getControlName(c) + path;
  } 
to not add the last dot  path.to.name.

Comment: No longer works. `formGroup[name]` gives me an error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; } | AbstractControl[]'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; } | AbstractControl[]'`. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

@lonix Too long for a comment...

`formGroup` is either `AbstractControl[]` or `{ [key: string]: AbstractControl }`, so just test for array and everything works as expected:

```js
export const getControlName = (control: AbstractControl): string | null => {
  if (control.parent == null) {
    return null;
  }

  const children = control.parent.controls;

  if (Array.isArray(children)) {
    for (let index = 0; index < children.length; index++) {
      if (children[index] === control) {
        return `${index}`;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  return Object.keys(children).find(name => control === children[name]) || null;
};
```